# Regular expression for one Alphabet and many numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression that check my string contains one alphabet+many digits.Eg, A546456 or B456 or N455,asp.net

I have tried

```
^[a-z|A-Z|]+[a-z|A-Z|0-9]+[0-9]*
```

and

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Isn't `\w\d+` working?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Something simple like `[a-zA-Z]\d+` might do the job.

Comment: @w0lf `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: change `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` to `[a-zA-Z][0-9]+`

Comment: @user3218114 : It checks alphabet and digits ,But in addition of this check I want to check that it has only one alphabet as I said in my question : A89729 or D98798

Comment: have you tried it? `[a-zA-Z]` checks for only one alphabet and `[0-9]+` checks for one and more digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression to validate if a string starts with a single letter A-Z in any case and has 1 or more digits and nothing else is: `^[A-Za-z]\d+$`

Explanation:

`^` ... beginning of string (or beginning of line in other context).

`[A-Za-z]` ... a character class definition for a single character (no multiplier appended) matching a letter in range A-Z in any case. `\w` cannot be used as it matches also an underscore and letters from other languages as for example German umlauts.

`\d` ... a digit which is equal the expression [0-9].

`+` ... previous expression (any digit) **1** or more times.

`$` ... end of string (or end of line in other context).

Be careful with a regular expression containing a backslash as used here for `\d` put into a string as the backslash character is in many programming/scripting languages also the escape character inside strings and must be therefore often escaped with one more backslash, i.e. `"^[A-Za-z]\\d+$"`